# How to visualise the complex data on EMR just like we visualise it on Databricks using display() method

Tags: pandas, dataframe, databricks, pyspark

I'm writing a pyspark job and I want to visualise the complex data on EMR just like we do on databricks using display which helps in testing.

Comment: Does df.show() work?

Comment: @mck no, it doesn't give the output like display() does using display() you can navigate the output in the proper structure but show() doesn't give the output like that.